# Sign in with google doesnt redirect on mobile but works on browser - Ionic3 with firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, oauth, ionic3, google-signin

I am developing an app using ionic 3 and firebase. I added google sign in functionality but when I press the button on the browser emulator it redirects to google sign in and then returns with the proper results. When I press the button on a real device it doesn't redirect and it gives an error about 0auth. On my firebase console, I have localhost and the "appnamme".firebaseapp.com registered at 0auth. I searched the web about other threads but some are not even answered and others give answers that are not relevant to my problem. Below is my code.

```
    async nativeGoogleLogin(): Promise<void>{
        try{
          const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
          const credential = await this.afAuth.auth.signInWithRedirect(provider)
        }catch(err){
          console.log(err);
        }
    }
getRedirectResult(){
    firebase.auth().getRedirectResult().then(function(result) {
      if (result.credential) {
        // This gives you a Google Access Token. You can use it to access the Google API.
        var token = result.credential;
        // ...
      }`enter code here
      // The signed-in user info.
      var user = result.user;
      console.lo`enter code here`g(user.email + '\n' + user.displayName + '\n' + user.uid + '\n' + user.phoneNumber);
      console.log('---\n' + token.providerId);
    }).catch(function(error) {
      // Handle Errors here.
      var errorCode = error.code;
      var errorMessage = error.message;
      // The email of the user's account used.
      var email = error.email;
      // The firebase.auth.AuthCredential type that was used.
      var credential = error.credential;
      // ...
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same issue  with ionic 3.9.2 and firebase 5.4.1

```
Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.4.0
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.0

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
   Cordova Platforms     : not available
   Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 1.1.1, (and 25 other plugins)

System:

   NodeJS : v8.11.3 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm    : 5.6.0
   OS     : Windows 10
```